# Looping through text file to construct query and display results in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to loop through a text file and run a query on the content of each line. The resulting data of each query should be displayed in `My_Repater`.

I've got the following code working, but it only fills the repeater with data from the last query. How can I fill the repeater line by line with the results from each query? Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
protected void txtUpload1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Define file upload control as fu
        FileUpload fu = FileUpload1;
        //Check to see if file is present
        if (fu.HasFile)
        {
            //Create StreamReader and pass contents of file
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fu.FileContent);
            //Open SQL connection
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mike_db"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();
            //Do the following until all file content has been read
            do
            {
                string item = reader.ReadLine();
                string qry = "select * from prod_class where item =" + "'" + item + "';";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                queryText.Text = qry;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                //Bind data to the repeater
                My_Repeater.DataSource = ds;
                My_Repeater.DataBind(); 
            }
            while (reader.Peek() != -1);
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: bind the data outside of the while loop. construct all the data in the loop to an outside variable then bind when you're done reading all the data.

Comment: also, i'm not sure, but `Repeater` might have an `AppendDataBoundItems` property, like `ComboBox`. This would make it so every time you call DataBind it will append instead of replace. Not sure if it has this though.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I was wondering the same about appending data instead of constructing it all at once. I'm looking up `AppendDataBoundItems` now

Comment: however, since you're not doing it async or anything, it will all be done at once anyway. check my answer for how I believe it SHOULD be done. Also, `AppendDataBoundItems` would require you to manually clear the repeater if you do a postback to get new data

Comment: Please Google SQL Injection. You are leaving yourself wide open to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what is going on with `string qry`. I will eventually turn it into a paramerterized query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a single query with all the id's (example below). Several comments to improve code:

1) First and most importantly you are leaving yourself open to SQL Injection attacks.

2) Learn to use the using statement on disposable objects (like SQLConnection)

3) A stored procedure would increase performance, you could then pass in all your id's in a table valued parameter.

```
protected void txtUpload1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Define file upload control as fu
    FileUpload fu = FileUpload1;
    //Check to see if file is present
    if (fu.HasFile)
    {
        //Create StreamReader and pass contents of file
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fu.FileContent);
        //Open SQL connection
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mike_db"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();

        string items = "";
        //Do the following until all file content has been read
        do
        {
            items += reader.ReadLine() + ",";

        }
        while (reader.Peek() != -1);

        //remove last comma
        items = items.Substring(0, items.Length -1);

        string qry = String.Format("select * from prod_class where item IN ({0})", items);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        queryText.Text = qry;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        //Bind data to the repeater
        My_Repeater.DataSource = ds;
        My_Repeater.DataBind(); 

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply. Everything looks good and makes sense except for the line `items += reader.ReadLine() + ",";`. I'm getting an error that says `Use of unassigned local variable 'items'`. EDIT: fixed this by using `string items = "";`

Comment: Sorry code was untested. Change to string items = "";

Comment: This works great. Had to adjust the query so that each item is encapsulated within ' ' and all items are encapsulated within ( ). Thanks again!

Comment: Great! I wasn't sure what data types your id was.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object to hold your data, fill it in the while loop, and then DataBind() the repeater after you're all done.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string MyValue1 { get; set; }
    public string MyValue2 { get; set; }
}

var myList = new List<MyObject>();
while(){
//...
myList.Add(new MyObject { MyValue1 = ds["myvalue1]", MyValue2 = ds["myvalue2"]});
}

My_Repeater.DataSource = myList;
My_Repeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is a great idea. However, I'm having issues with this: `MyValue1 = ds["myvalue1"]` What should I replace `["myvalue1"]` with? I tried using indexing `ds[0]` and the name of the field from the database `ds["item"]`. Both throw errors.

Comment: You may need to cast you values from the data source.  MyValue1 = ds["myvalue1"].ToString(), MyValue2 = ds["myvalue2"].ToString()

Comment: It throws the following error whether or not I use `.ToString()`: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataSet'`

Comment: i always forget how to actually read from datasets, I always use Linq. do some google research on how to read from datasets, it's not really pertinent to the question at hand. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6.aspx